# why does this C/C++ code helps in taking fast input

Tags: c, performance

I took this code from this link https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/1715623
and I am not able to understand how the *scan()* function helps in taking fast input

```
#define g getchar_unlocked()
int scan()//fast input output
{
    int t=0;
    char c;
    c=g;
    while(c<'0' || c>'9')
        c=g;
    while(c>='0' && c<='9')
    {
        t=(t<<3)+(t<<1)+c-'0';
        c=g;
    }//end fast input output
    return(t);
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend using as an example any code that hides functions behind a define to make it a single character.

Comment: Who said it is "fast"? "fast" comparing to what?

Comment: `(t<<3)+(t<<1)` is equivalent to `t * 10`. This code is an attempt to forcibly optimize out multiplication.

Comment: A pretty futile attempt I would say...

Comment: So it is receiving digits, using the shifts to "optimize out" multiplication. What is this optimized over, scanf? doing the same loop with getch and *10?

Comment: `getchar` is probably faster than `scanf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane *One* `getchar` maybe...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have not been on CodeChef but on another one, I regularly cook my own input using `fgets` which is *considerably* faster than `scanf`.

Comment: Won't the actual IO time to read in the number in be significantly slower than whatever you use to parse it? Or whatever algorithm you then feed the number into? Why would 'fast' matter here?

Comment: @Rup 'fast' matters here because these sites have a tight execution time limit, and on some it can be possible to exceed the time limit *just by reading the data* without even beginning to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

User defined function `scan()` uses lib function [`getchar_unlocked()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar_unlocked) which is faster than `getchar()` and any other standart input methods since it's **not thread safe**.

Inner function loops are used to consider only numeric input (and uses shift operators instead of multiplying for extra performance gain which must be tested before used).

And this function contains possible int overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's basically atoi with getchar. It ignores leading non numeric characters then creates an integer of the string numerals, exiting when numeric numbers stop. Scan is probably not the right name for this, it should be Atoi(), or ScanNum()? Probably doesn't work for when the integer is big due to integer overflow issues.

I'd be surprised if this is faster than atoi() not sure why they didn't use isdigit() either.

Unlike the California University code, doesn't check for a sign, nor does it use the register keyword.